# Problems with jquery click function firing twice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have been googling for a couple of hours now, but I just can't figure it out. This is the script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('article').readmore({
        maxHeight: 75,
        speed: 300,
        moreLink: '<a href="#">Read more...</a>',
        lessLink: '<a href="#">Read less...</a>'
    });

    $('.plus-button').click(function(){
        var postid = $(this).data('postid');
        $(this).siblings('.minus-button').removeClass('disliked');    
        $(this).toggleClass('liked');

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"php/votesystem.php",
            dataType : 'html',
            data:'act=like&postid='+postid,
            context: this,
            success: function(data){
                $(this).html(data);
            }
        });
    });
    $('.minus-button').click(function(){
        var postid = $(this).data('postid');
        $(this).siblings('.plus-button').removeClass('liked');    
        $(this).toggleClass('disliked');

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"php/votesystem.php",
            dataType : 'html',
            data:'act=dislike&postid='+postid,
            context: this,
            success: function(data){
                $(this).html(data);
            }
        });
    }); 

    $("#infobox").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });     





});
$("#loader").hide();
    var load = 0;
    var nbr = "<?php echo $nbr; ?>";
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
        {
            $("#loader").show();
            load++;
            if(load * 10 > nbr){
                $("#messages").text("No more posts");
                $("#loader").hide();
            }
            else{
                $.post("php/newquery.php",{load:load},function(data){
                    $("#contentwrapper").append(data);
                    $("#loader").hide();


                    $('.plus-button').on("click", function(){
                        var postid = $(this).data('postid');
                        $(this).siblings('.minus-button').removeClass('disliked');    
                        $(this).toggleClass('liked');

                        $.ajax({
                            type:"POST",
                            url:"php/votesystem.php",
                            dataType : 'html',
                            data:'act=like&postid='+postid,
                            context: this,
                            success: function(data){
                                $(this).html(data);
                                alert("Liked");
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    $('.minus-button').on("click", function(){
                        var postid = $(this).data('postid');
                        $(this).siblings('.plus-button').removeClass('liked');    
                        $(this).toggleClass('disliked');

                        $.ajax({
                            type:"POST",
                            url:"php/votesystem.php",
                            dataType : 'html',
                            data:'act=dislike&postid='+postid,
                            context: this,
                            success: function(data){
                                $(this).html(data);
                                alert("Disliked");
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    $('article').readmore({
                        maxHeight: 75,
                        speed: 300,
                        moreLink: '<a href="#">Read more...</a>',
                        lessLink: '<a href="#">Read less...</a>'
                    });



                });

            }

        }
    });
</script>
```

PS: Alerts are only used for troubleshooting.

The problem is that when the new items are loaded with the infinite scroll part of the script and I click the post items I get the alert "liked" or "disliked" *twice* each time I click either one of them. I do realize I have the script copied, but I need to have the script both inside and outside of the infinite scroll script for it to work. The article thing is just a read more plugin (also need this both inside and outside of infinite scroll). I have tried moving things around, but nothing seems to work. And to clarify: I only have problems after the new posts are loaded. The first posts outside infinite scroll works fine.

newquery.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("connect.php");
require_once("config.php");
$load = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['load'])) * 10;

$query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE totalupvotes < $trendmin AND deleted=0 ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT " . $load . ",10");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $postloopid = $row['id'];
    echo '<div id="postlist">
        <div style="width:400px; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold;">
        <a target="_blank" href="post.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['title'] . '</a>
        </div><br />
        <article class="slide">' . nl2br($row['post']) . '</article>
        <br />';
        include("votebox.php");
        echo '

        <br />
        by <a style="font-size:18px;" href="profile.php?id=' . $row['submittedby'] . '">' . $row['submitteduser'] . '</a>';
        echo ' at <span style="font-size:12px;">' . $row['added'] . '</span><span style="float:right; margin-right: 10px;"><a target="_blank" href="post.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '#commentfield">' . $row['totalcomments'] . ' comments</a></span></div>';
}

?>
```

Votebox.php included in all the posts listed:

```
<?php
// If postid is from frontpage use $postloopid as $postid
if(isset($postloopid)){
    $postid = $postloopid;
}

include("connect.php");






// If user logged in show votebox
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){

    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

    $sql2 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id='$postid' AND deleted=0");

    if($sql2){

        $voterow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2);



         $checkupvote = $voterow['upvoters'];

         $checkdownvote = $voterow['downvoters'];

         $checkupvote = explode(" ",$checkupvote);

         $checkdownvote = explode(" ",$checkdownvote);

         if($checkupvote = array_search($userid,$checkupvote) == true){

            echo '<div class="voteboxwrapper">';

            echo '<div class="plus-button liked" data-postid="' . $postid . '" name="like">+ ' . $voterow['totalupvotes'] . '</div>';

            echo '<div class="minus-button" data-postid="' . $postid . '" name="dislike">- ' . $voterow['totaldownvotes'] . '</div>';

            echo $postid;

            echo '</div>';


         }

         elseif($checkdownvote = array_search($userid,$checkdownvote) == true){

             echo '<div class="voteboxwrapper">';

            echo '<div class="plus-button" data-postid="' . $postid . '" name="like">+ ' . $voterow['totalupvotes'] . '</div>';

            echo '<div class="minus-button disliked" data-postid="' . $postid . '" name="dislike">- ' . $voterow['totaldownvotes'] . '</div>';

            echo $postid;

            echo '</div>';


         }

         else{

             echo '<div class="voteboxwrapper">';

            echo '<div class="plus-button" data-postid="' . $postid . '" name="like">+ ' . $voterow['totalupvotes'] . '</div>';

            echo '<div class="minus-button" data-postid="' . $postid . '" name="dislike">- ' . $voterow['totaldownvotes'] . '</div>';

            echo $postid;

            echo '</div>';

         }

    }
    else {
        echo 'No result <br />';

    }

}
else {
    echo 'Cant find user';
}


?>
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: Have tried .off() and .unbind() all ways I could think of. I still get the double and triple popups of "liked" and "disliked" (supposed to be only 1). Any ideas except unbind and off?

EDIT2: Updated all scripts with new suggestions. Still don't work.

Comment: Have you tried to unbind the click event before binding it?  Most likely it is getting double bound.

Comment: No. How do you do that? I don't really do jquery. Scripts are downloaded and customized with my noob knowledge.

Comment: @SindreSørensen To remove an event listener, use [**`off()`**](http://api.jquery.com/off/) or, depending on your jQuery version, use [**`unbind()`**](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) (it is depreciated as of 1.7).

Comment: FYI, you are creating a possible performance nightmare here … http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Comment: Hehe, problem for another day.

Comment: Still having problems..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `$('.plus-button').click(...` you want to use `$('.plus-button').one('click', ...` which, as the name suggests, binds once and only once!

[see the official docs](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Answer (score -1):

Try moving `$(window).scroll.....` outside of document ready function

Comment: Tried it, didn't work either. It's weird though, I don't have a problem with the first 10 posts loaded(without jq), and the first batch of posts(10) loaded from infinite scroll works fine too. The next 10 pots loaded after that doesn't work. I've tried checking if there's a pattern in which posts doesn't work, but it seems kindof random. Each "batch" of posts loaded has like a chance of getting bugged? Is that even possible

Comment: Hell no there is no chance it's all about programming, try removing the bind function and use onclick instead so that the event will be dispatched once

Comment: Tried it both inside and outside of document ready, but still doesn't work.

Comment: No I mean remove the .click(function(){ .... And replace it with function(){... outside the document ready then add onclick="yourFunction()" to html element

Comment: Ah.. Good idea. Gonna try that later.

Comment: Ok @ahmad that actually solved the problem. But now the $(this).toggleClass('liked'); doesn't work. Seems that $(this) is not recognized. How can I fix it?

Comment: Well replace onclick="yourFunction()" by onclick="yourFunction($(this));" and also replace in your javascript code function yourFunction(){} with function yourFunction(e){} and you will not use $(this).toggleClass('liked') but e.toggleClass('liked') instead